# get access to soundcloud tracks

Tags: soundcloud

I'd like to built an application for analysis and classifications of tracks (everyday sound tracks instead of speech or music) recorded and/or streamed by soundcloud.

The idea is to use existing soundcloud infastructure (database, record, share, comment...) and just add an analysis level in between.

It is possible trought the API to access to the track binary files? We'd like to process some of them.

Is there also a way to access to the audio stream durring recording? it's for live classification task.

Thanks

Boris

Answer (score 0):

Some users allow for their tracks to be downloaded, others don't. On one of the downloadable tracks, the track information will have a `download_url`, and you can download and process that however you like. As for accessing the stream during recording, at that point in time, the file doesn't exist on SoundCloud yet (it's only uploaded once the recording is complete). You could write your own Flash recorder or use the Web Audio API to get audio information during recording.